# configurar zona horaria JDBC driver java

Tags: java, mysql

presento un error al ejecutar mi codigo de parte de la persistencia el cual es el siguiente

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora est. Pac?fico, Sudam?ric' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

¿Donde se configura la zona horaria para solucionar ese problema?

utilizo el siguiente driver de mysql

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Puedes configurarlo en la URL de la conexion:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) la respuesta en ingles.

Ademas creo, como muestra el error SQL con `?`, que deberias de configurar MySQL con encoding ISO-8859-1 para que permita caracteres como la ñ al tratar de insertar VARCHARS y no se corrompa tu data.

Answer (score 10):

También se puede configurar la zona horaria de MySQL ejecutando esta query y asi evitar modificar la URL

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-3:00';
```

Comment: ArielManto: Gracias por tu valiosa aportación, me soluciono el problema con sólo restar el tiempo en 3:00 hrs.

Comment: Con esto me lo soluciono impecablemente y efectivamente no hay que modificar la línea de conexión para nada, recomiendo esta respuesta al 100%

Answer (score 3):

En mi caso, estoy utilizando SpringFramework, con configuración mediante xml.

Lo solucioné añadiendo al final del valor de la property url : ?serverTimezone=UTC

Quedando algo como:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miBBDD?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="miPassword"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenia el mismo error y lo solucione agregando a la Url de la db :

```
?serverTimezone=UTC
```

ejemplo :

```
public String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombreDB?serverTimezone=UTC";
```

espero te sirva!:3

Answer (score 1):

Siempre me ha funcionado agregar en la ruta de la BD, despues del nombre de la base de datos lo siguiente: ?serverTimezone=UTC
A modo de ejemplo dejo una ruta para que sea mas claro:
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioteca?serverTimezone=UTC","root","root"

Espero funcione sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias aquí encontrare la solución al error de conexión de mysqlcon java,se soluciono añadiendo al

```
url: ?serverTimezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solucioné añadiendo el nombre del puerto completo (ej:"128.0.0.1:3306/db) y seguidamente adjunté lo siguiente:

`?serverTimezone=UTC`

Answer (score -2):

A veces podrías darse el caso que UTC no te funciona como deseas quizás debas usar alternativas como:
 1. UTC
 2. CST
 3. EST
 4. GMT

depende como se acomode a los registros en tu base sino podrías tener una fecha en la base y otra totalmente distinta e tu aplicación.