# Error en consulta con Mysql y java. SQLException: The server time zone value is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Quiero realizar una aplicación con las funciones básicas para interactuar con una base de datos, a lo cual seria insertar, modificar y eliminar.

Siguiendo los ejemplos mostrados en la documentación de **MySQL** para lo cual
uso ejemplo que muestran para la conexión con la base de datos mostrada [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).
A lo cual mi codigo queda de la siguiente manera en java

```
public Connection conectarMySQL() {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + "/" + database + "?"
                + "user=" + username + "&password=" + password);
        // Do something with the Connection
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }

    return conn;
}
```

Lo siguiente que hice fue realizar una consulta de prueba en otro metodo aparte tal como lo muestra la documentación [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements.html).
La consulta es la siguiente

```
SELECT nombre FROM alumnos
```

Quedando mi código en java de la siguiente manera

```
public void consulta() {
    try {
        stmt = conectarMySQL().createStatement();
        //stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT nombre FROM alumnos");

        // or alternatively, if you don't know ahead of time that
        // the query will be a SELECT...
        /*if (stmt.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar")) {
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        }*/
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

A lo cual me manda lo siguiente

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano central (M�xic' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
SQLState: 01S00
VendorError: 0
    at DB.Conexion.consulta(Conexion.java:53)
    at Proveedores.Registrar_Modificar_proveedor.jButton1ActionPerformed(Registrar_Modificar_proveedor.java:162)
    at Proveedores.Registrar_Modificar_proveedor.access$000(Registrar_Modificar_proveedor.java:17)
    at Proveedores.Registrar_Modificar_proveedor$1.actionPerformed(Registrar_Modificar_proveedor.java:76)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en la zona horaria que tiene **MySQL** para lo cual se puede dar solución de dos maneras

1. La primera solución fue usar la siguiente url de conexión.

   `localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`
2. La otra forma es cambiar en la base de datos la zona horaria con el siguiente comando.

   `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-3:00';`

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48946/76401) de donde sale las respuestas